# Can't Install or Try Ubuntu (via DVD or USB)

Tags: boot, system-installation, 14.10, iso

Disclaimer: I'm extremely new to Linux. I've been searching google and askubuntu.com for four days trying to get this to work and I think I'm in over my head.

I'm trying to install on Toshiba Satellite running an AMD Phenom II quad core. I've so far tried burning the following to DVDs but sadly nothing is working.

1. ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso
2. ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-amd64.iso
3. mini.iso
4. linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso
5. Fedora-Live-Desktop-i686-20-1.iso
6. archbang-rc-2014.12.06-x86_64.iso

I've also attempted to use Unetbootin and Universal-USB-Installer to make a bootable USB but ended up with much the same results.

The only thing that seems to allow me to load into a linux environment is Parted Magic.

The best I get is the following which happens if I just let the DVD do its thing on boot and not mess with the options:

```
General Error Mounting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
 CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot.
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Adding "nomodeset" sends me to a kernel panic with the last line looking like this (promising me a text console that never shows):

```
drm_kms_helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: Attempted to use [Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.8.exe](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) with the Ubuntu 14.10 and make the local drive a live CD. Booting off this gets me a “BusyBox initramfs” prompt instead of the maintenance shell.

Comment: Exactly how are you burning the image to disk or USB drive?

Comment: I've been double clicking on the file in Windows 7 pro. It loads a simple interface to burn images to disk.

Comment: So you're **sure** you're burning the image in a way that re-creates the original disk structure and all it's files, or are you simply burning the .iso to the DVD as one file on a data disk? If look at that DVD or USB using Windows' file manager, what do you see?

Comment: Looking at it on my windows machine, the DVD and USB show the original structure. All the appropriate directories (boot,casper, .disk, etc..)

Comment: try right clicking instead of double clicking  on iso and choose burn disk image

Comment: if nothing happens you may have to set windows disk image burner in Control Panel>Default Programs

Comment: That pulled up the same program I'd been using "Windows Disc Image Burner" but I let it burn another disk for grins. Booted the disk and got a similar result. Maintenance shell and kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init!

Comment: you have been remotely hacked sounds like......